# How to inspect data sent to server from android app

Tags: android, web, http-post

Can we check which data is sent to the server from an android app just like we can check request headers, form data etc in chrome dev tools??

Comment: try an http inspector like chuck: https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools that help with that problem:

https://github.com/facebook/stetho (Here you can actually use chrome dev tools)

https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck

https://www.charlesproxy.com/

More info: https://proandroiddev.com/various-methods-to-debug-http-traffic-in-the-android-application-8685b9183418

Comment: Thanks. but these are tool mostly for the app we are developing. I want to know about any app which i install from play store etc.

Comment: I understand, that's harder and as Krupson mentioned with modern Android sometimes even impossible. But Charles will also help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you need to read HTTP communication from another app. You need to set up proxy server on your local computer and then redirect traffic through that proxy on your phone. I use Proxyman (https://proxyman.io/). But remember that there are some limitations. First of all you will need to create your local SSL certificate and add it to trusted store on your phone, also you will probably need Android below 7 because they added some security configs for apps which makes it harder to sniff. Next thing is that some apps may pin their SSL certificates and despite your custom cert is in trusted store app may reject connection.